# Lennard Jones Potential returning inf for kinetic energy

Tags: c++, simulation

I am trying to simulate a Lennard Jones potential for a 50 particle system (argon m = 40amu), my code compiles and runs well but has issues when calculating  kinetic energies. I am new to C++ coding and would love some insight on where the problem is. printing values at runtime haven't been any help in locating the bug. I was trying to use a velocity verlet algorithm for the integration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream> 


int main()
{

//std::ofstream fout;
//fout.open("HW2.txt");
std::ofstream out("HW2.txt");

static const double m = 40; // 40 amu Convert later
static const double e = 0.103; // electron-volts
static const double s = 3.405; // angstroms
double t = 0.0;// in ps
static const double dt = 0.05;
static const double stop = 50;// 50 ps

double atoms_x [50];
double atoms_y [50];
double atoms_vx [50];
double atoms_vy [50];
double atoms_fx [50];
double atoms_fy [50];

int i = 0; // iteration var (atoms initial)

while (i < 50) {

    atoms_vx[i] = 0.0;
    atoms_vy[i] = 0.0;

    atoms_x[i] = i % 5;
    atoms_y[i] = i / 5;


    i++;

}


int q = 0;

while (q < 50) {

    int r = 0;


    while (r < 50) {

        if (q == r) {
            r++;
            continue; // break for the i=j case
        }
        if (r < q) {
            r++;
            continue; // break for double count
        }

        double dx = atoms_x[r] - atoms_x[q];
        double dy = atoms_y[r] - atoms_y[q];
        double sqr_dx = pow(dx, 2.0);
        double sqr_dy = pow(dy, 2.0);
        double inner = sqr_dx + sqr_dy;
        double rij = pow(inner, 0.5);

        

        double powsix = s / rij;
        double fxadd = (((24 * e * pow(s, 6) * dx) / (pow(rij, 8))) * (1 - 2 * pow(powsix, 6)));

        double fyadd = (((24 * e * pow(s, 6) * dy) / (pow(rij, 8))) * (1 - 2 * pow(powsix, 6)));

        atoms_fx[q] -= fxadd;
        atoms_fy[q] -= fyadd;

        atoms_fx[r] += fxadd;
        atoms_fy[r] += fyadd;

            r++;
    }
    q++;
}




while (t < stop) {

    double atoms_x1[50];
    double atoms_y1[50];
    double atoms_vx1[50];
    double atoms_vy1[50];
    double atoms_fx1[50];
    double atoms_fy1[50];

    double utot = 0;
    double ktot = 0;

    int a = 0; // iteration var (atoms main)

    while (a < 50) {

        

        atoms_x1[a] = atoms_x[a] + dt * atoms_vx[a] - (dt * dt * atoms_fx[a]) / (2 * m);
        atoms_y1[a] = atoms_y[a] + dt * atoms_vy[a] - (dt * dt * atoms_fy[a]) / (2 * m);
        a++;

    }


    int q = 0;

    while (q < 50) {

        int r = 0;


        while (r < 50) {

            if (q == r) {
                r++;
                continue; // break for the i=j case
            }
            if (r < q) {
                r++;
                continue; // break for double count
            }

            double dx = atoms_x1[q] - atoms_x1[r];
            double dy = atoms_y1[q] - atoms_y1[r];
            double sqr_dx = pow(dx, 2.0);
            double sqr_dy = pow(dy, 2.0);
            double inner = sqr_dx + sqr_dy;
            double rij = pow(inner, 0.5);

            double powsix = s / rij;
            double fxadd = (((24 * e * pow(s, 6) * dx) / (pow(rij, 8))) * (1 - 2 * pow(powsix, 6)));

            double fyadd = (((24 * e * pow(s, 6) * dy) / (pow(rij, 8))) * (1 - 2 * pow(powsix, 6)));

            atoms_fx1[q] -= fxadd;
            atoms_fy1[q] -= fyadd;

            atoms_fx1[r] += fxadd;
            atoms_fy1[r] += fyadd;
            
            double uadd = 4 * e * (pow(powsix, 12) - pow(powsix, 6));
            utot += uadd;
            
            
            r++;
        }
        q++;
    }

    int va = 0;

    while (va < 50) {

        atoms_vx1[va] = atoms_vx[va] + (dt * (atoms_fx[va] + atoms_fx1[va]) / (2 * m));
        atoms_vy1[va] = atoms_vy[va] + (dt * (atoms_fy[va] + atoms_fy1[va]) / (2 * m));

        double kadd = 0.5 * m * (pow(atoms_vy1[va], 2) + pow(atoms_vx1[va], 2));
        ktot += kadd;

        
        va++;

    }

    int n = 0;
    while (n < 50) {

        atoms_x[n] = atoms_x1[n];
        atoms_y[n] = atoms_y1[n];
        atoms_vx[n] = atoms_vx1[n];
        atoms_vy[n] = atoms_vy1[n];
        atoms_fx[n] = atoms_fx1[n];
        atoms_fy[n] = atoms_fy1[n];

        n++;

    }
    t += dt;      
    std::cout << utot << "\t" << ktot << "\t" << t << "\n" ;
}
for (int z = 50 - 1; z >= 0; z--)
    std::cout << atoms_x[z] << "\t" << atoms_y[z] << "\t" << z << "\n" ;
}
```

some of the output is listed below it is  total potential energy - total kinetic energy - time:

```
3.9917e+07      inf     0.05
7.80208e+07     inf     0.1
5.6369e+06      inf     0.15
2.78139e+09     inf     0.2
-7.5547e-07     inf     0.25
-8.20938e-10    inf     0.3
-4.56581e-08    inf     0.35
-5.83223e-12    inf     0.4
-8.9669e-13     inf     0.45
-1.78096e-13    inf     0.5
-4.28183e-14    inf     0.55
-1.19697e-14    inf     0.6
-3.78067e-15    inf     0.65
-1.32112e-15    inf     0.7
-5.02862e-16    inf     0.75
-2.06359e-16    inf     0.8
-9.13939e-17    inf     0.85
-4.63778e-17    inf     0.9
-4.14284e-17    inf     0.95
-2.06414e-16    inf     1
.
.
.
-2.32717e-35    inf     49
-2.30239e-35    inf     49.05
-2.2779e-35     inf     49.1
-2.25368e-35    inf     49.15
-2.22975e-35    inf     49.2
-2.20609e-35    inf     49.25
-2.1827e-35     inf     49.3
-2.15957e-35    inf     49.35
-2.13671e-35    inf     49.4
-2.11412e-35    inf     49.45
-2.09177e-35    inf     49.5
-2.06969e-35    inf     49.55
-2.04785e-35    inf     49.6
-2.02627e-35    inf     49.65
-2.00493e-35    inf     49.7
-1.98383e-35    inf     49.75
-1.96297e-35    inf     49.8
-1.94235e-35    inf     49.85
-1.92196e-35    inf     49.9
-1.9018e-35     inf     49.95
-1.88187e-35    inf     50
-1.86216e-35    inf     50.05
```

Comment: Are you working in a specific ensemble (NVE, NVT)? I see nothing that limits the rising kinetic energy, besides the number of atoms

Comment: no I had no ensemble in mind I was looking for a final structure to emerge. the kinetic energies were calculated to give me some understanding of the dynamics of the system.

Comment: Can you include some sample output in the question? Is it always infinity or does it get larger and larger as the simulation progresses?

Comment: check now, it seems to always be inf, the potentoal energy does seem to steadily increase.

Comment: One thing I can think of is you say you’re going to convert m but you never actually do that, either the comment needs to go or the value should be converted when needed

Comment: I don't see where you initialize `atoms_fx` or `atoms_fy`.

Comment: I thought that the mass would be converted once the data was taken during my analysis. and I never really initialize atoms_fx and atoms_fy I just set the values when I calculate the forces.

Comment: Your first access to them is with `atoms_fx[q] -= fxadd;`, which results in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: I assumed that they would be set to zero if I left them un-initialized. Do I need a loop to make all their elements 0 before I add calculations to them?

Comment: Because they are local variables, they will be uninitialized. You can do it with a loop, or with `double atoms_fx [50] = {0};` if you're not using an old compiler.

Comment: this seemed to fix my "inf" issue, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `atoms_fx` and `atoms_fy` are uninitialized (because they are local variables, their initial values are Undefined). The first access to them (`atoms_fx[q] -= fxadd;`) results in Undefined Behavior because of this.

You can initialize them with a loop, or with

```
double atoms_fx [50] = {0};
```

if you're not using an old compiler.